# Error Correction For The Code

Tags: java

```
int i = 0;
Float[] arr =null;
Float arr2 [] = null;
Iterator itr = minMaxVal.keySet().iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    arr = minMaxVal.get(i);
    arr2[i] = (float) arr[0];
    i++;
}
java.util.Arrays.sort(arr2);
return arr2[0];
```

It throws an NulPointException at `arr2[i] = (float) arr[0];`

How can overcome this. Thank You in advance....

Comment: `float temp = (Float) null;` throws NulPointException

Comment: I have Commented it in the code!!! thanks for reminding!!!

Comment: Are you sure the NullPointerException is thrown at that line. The line `flaot temp = (Float) null;` should throw a NPE as well as a null reference cannot be converted to a primitive float value.

Comment: flaot temp = (Float) null; has been removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all the values in `arr` are null. Converting a null value into a primitive float would obviously fail. as in the statement `arr2[i] = (float) arr[0];` first initialize the array `arr` and then do the assignment

Answer (score 1):

The NullPointerException is thrown because the values of `arr` and `arr2` are null. For starters, you have to initialize the arrays `arr` and `arr0`:

```
float[] arr = new float[n];
float[] arr2 = new float[m];
```

where n and m are the respective sizes of each array or

```
float[] arr = {1f, 2f, 3f, ...};
float[] arr2 = {1f, 2f, 3f, ...};
```

where `1f, 2f, 3f` should be replaced with the actual values of the arrays.

The letter `f` or `F` can be used to indicate that the number is a `float` instead of an `int`. Furthermore, `1.3f` is a `float` but `1.3` is a `double`.